# Error when trying to retrieve data from the network

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas

When deploying a solution to a test environment:

- One user has been added and assigned the role "Basic user" - for testing purposes, this user will only be able to use the app but not the app maker nor the backend data.
- The user opens the app but upon opening the following error message is displayed:

  Error when trying to retrieve data from the network: Principal user (Id=xxa, type=8, roleCount=1, privilegeCount=438, accessMode='0 Read-Write', MetadataCachePrivilegesCount=4023, businessUnitId=xxx), is missing prvReadcre05_Formadores privilege (Id=1cxxx) on OTC=10438 for entity 'cre05_formadores' (LocalizedName='Formadores'). context.Caller=07xxx. Consider adding miss...

So it seems the user has no privileges to access the Dataverse tables.

What kind of configurations should be done in this environment?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve your issue either extend the existing "Basic user" or create a new security role that will provide read privilege for table cre05_formadores that is mentioned in the error log. You can find more information by checking the following links:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/admin/security-roles-privileges#define-the-privileges-and-properties-of-a-security-role

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/admin/database-security